# Llamar a una Función de una clase en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy programando en tres capas, en la segunda capa que es la lógica tengo en una clase llamada nOperadores. El sig. código para validar números de CUIT en un TextBox.

```
    public static int CalcularDigitoCuit(string cuit)
    {
        int[] mult = new[] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        char[] nums = cuit.ToCharArray();
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mult.Length; i++)
        {
            total += int.Parse(nums[i].ToString()) * mult[i];
        }
        int resto = total % 11;
        return resto == 0 ? 0 : resto == 1 ? 9 : 11 - resto;
    }

    public static bool ValidarCuit(string cuit)
    {
        if (cuit == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        cuit = cuit.Replace("-", string.Empty);
        if (cuit.Length != 11)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            int calculado = CalcularDigitoCuit(cuit);
            int digito = int.Parse(cuit.Substring(10));
            return calculado == digito;
        }
    }
```

En la tercera capa que es la de presentación, en un formulario puse el sig. código para poder llamar a la función de la clase nOperadores

```
    private void ValidarCuit()
    {
        nOperadores.ValidarCuit(this.txtNumerodoc.Text);
    }
```

Por último, en un botón llamo a la función ValidarCuit(); pero no funciona, no me arroja ningún error, directamente no funciona.

En el botón tengo este código:

```
ValidarCuit();
```

Comment: Si pones un breakpoint en el evento click del boton puedes validar que se detiene el brekpoint ? y ejecutas paso a paso ingresa a la funciona de validar ? El codigo parece estar correcto, por eso mediante debug es que se puede determinar si esta ingresando

Comment: Es que el código que muestras, no realiza ninguna salida visible para el usuario, hace `MessageBox.Show((nOperadores.ValidarCuit(this.txtNumerodoc.Text).ToString())` y ahí vas a ver si tu función devolvió verdadero o falso

Comment: Si agregas a tu pregunta el error, te podria ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

en tu vista agrega un control label (lbValidacion)y en tu funcion de ValidarCuit puedes agregar
el resultado hacia el usuario

```
 private void ValidarCuit()
    {
      var esValidoCuit=  nOperadores.ValidarCuit(this.txtNumerodoc.Text);

   if(esValidoCuit==true)
{
   this.lbValidacion.Text="Es un digito valido";
}
else{
    this.lbValidaction.Text="Es un digito invalido";
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar la librería https://github.com/pixelario/CUIT

```
Install-Package Pixelario.CUIT -Version 0.10.3
```

Instancias tipos de datos CUIT que tienen su método IsValid()

Ejemplo:

```
var cuit = CUIT.Parse(
    cuit: this.txtNumerodoc.Text);

if(cuit.IsValid())
{
   this.lbValidacion.Text="Es un digito valido";
}
else 
{
    this.lbValidaction.Text="Es un digito invalido";
}
```